# Why do all my pages have the Expires http header that I have not set?

Tags: apache, expires

I have **max-age** set in my **.htaccess** file, so I am not worried, just intrigued.

All my pages have the same expiry date

`Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT`

I haven't set it.  Where is this value coming from ?

my htaccess where I am setting max-age

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

# 1 hour
<filesMatch ".(css|html|shtml|php|xml)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
# 2 days
<filesMatch ".(js)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
# 1 month
<filesMatch ".(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|avi|mov|svg)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
# never
<filesMatch ".(rar|zip|txt)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Are these "pages" _dynamically_ generated? Or do they map to actual files? "I have max-age set in my .htaccess file" - How exactly are you setting this? If you use mod_expires to set your caching headers then this also sets the `Expires` header so should override this inconsistent header. (mod_expires sets both `Cache-Control: max-age` and `Expires` headers)

Comment: They are all php files, so I guess dynamically generated.

Comment: That's set in PHP's [session_cache_limiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) by using the `nocache` value. You could disable that by setting it to null `''`, but generally you don't want dynamic content to be cached by the browser.

Comment: @dan I am setting max-age, so expires has no effect, its just bulking up the header

Comment: @dan That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @dan - you should put that as an answer, so we can finish this one off.